# Exponential operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, derivatives, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a linear operator from $H$ to itself.  If we define $\exp(T)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{T^n}{n!}$ then how do we prove the function $f(\lambda)=exp(\lambda T)$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is differentiable on a Hilbert space?

Comment: What is the variable now, $\lambda$? And the function, $\lambda\mapsto\exp(\lambda T)$ for a fixed $T$?

Comment: i fixed the question

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you saying that $T$ is a linear operator from a Hilbert Space to itself? And you want to know whether the map $f$ in question is a differentiable map from the complex numbers to the space of linear operators on the Hilbert Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(\lambda)-f(0)}{\lambda}=\frac{\exp(\lambda T)-Id}{\lambda} = \frac1\lambda\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^nT^n}{n!} \right) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n-1}T^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Plus the fact that $f(\lambda + \mu) = f(\lambda)f(\mu)$.

Comment: Yes, yes, I wanted to add it.

Comment: Apparently there was no need :-)